# How do I reinstall pip and its packages when pip doesn't work?

Tags: linux, python, arch-linux, pip

When I tried to install a google pip package it broke my pip installation and now I can't use pip to install or remove anything. I know I should have used a virtualenv but I already didn't.

If I just delete the site-packages folder on linux at

```
/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages
/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages
```

to reinstall everything will that fix it? Or will this just break things further?

There's this [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7387453/how-to-reset-site-packages), but it's 10 years old and they just tell the user to use pip to uninstall things, which won't work in my case.

For what it's worth, this is the error, but I don't think there's any easy fix for this other than removing and reinstalling everything.

```
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 223, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 180, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 305, in run
    resolver = self.make_resolver(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 295, in make_resolver
    import pip._internal.resolution.resolvelib.resolver
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/resolver.py", line 25, in <module>
    from .factory import Factory
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/factory.py", line 33, in <module>
    from .found_candidates import FoundCandidates
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/found_candidates.py", line 13, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.six.moves import collections_abc  # type: ignore
ImportError: cannot import name 'collections_abc' from 'six.moves' (unknown location)
```

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply reinstall it via your package manager.

From your selected flair I can see you use arch.

To remove pip and all of its config files run:

```
sudo pacman -Rns python-pip
```

Afterwards reinstall it via:

```
sudo pacman -S python-pip
```

Comment: Reinstalling it through the package manager doesn't reinstall the packages to my understanding though, just pip. Somewhere one of the packages are broken and I think that's what's preventing me from using pip

Comment: Do you think if I uninstalled python it would remove the pip packages too?

Comment: Pacman will in fact not uninstall any pip packages. Removing the site-packages folder should do that. Also it is very unlikely that any installed python package itself will prevent pip from running.